# OSQA on Centos 6.3 64bit with Nginx + Sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, nginx, vhosts, osqa

I tried to install OSQA on my server with Centos 6.3 and Nginx. I use vhosts to park 3 domain to this server. I tried to following this guide to install OSQA: http://fartersoft.com/blog/2011/02/11/running-osqa-with-nginx-and-uwsgi-virtualhosting-mode-with-dynamicapps/

It displays a 500 error.

1. I have a profile when install uwsgi
2. I can't find /etc/nginx/sites-enabled folder

I tried any method to install it but can't make it work.

Comment: So, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: thanks for remind me to add more detail to question, I will add it now